# DataColumn.Expression aritmetic operation of two String columns in a SLC

Tags: c#

I don't know a lot about C#, but I'm find my selft with a problem that I would like to acomplish within a line of code.

I'm working in a `DataColumn` base on the following `Expression = "[Col1] * [Col2]"` both of the columns  are string type, but has decimal type data within.

So for example if `Col1 = "12" & Col2 = "2"` what I spect to have is "24", but in this case I'm having and error `Cannot perform '*' operation on System.String and System.String.`

The code:

```
        DataColumn CalculatedColumn = new DataColumn();
        CalculatedColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        CalculatedColumn.ColumnName = Column_Name;
        CalculatedColumn.Expression = Expression;

        Collection.Columns.Add(CalculatedColumn);

        New_Collection = Collection;
```

Comment: use `Convert.ToDecimal(x)* Convert.ToDecimal(y) `

Comment: @viveknuna Thanks, I've tried and got a different error "stage: The expression contains undefined function call Convert.ToDecimal()".

Comment: how are you calling it, can you show the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the special expression language built into DataTables. The syntax is rather limited, however it [does support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netcore-3.1#functions) `Convert`:

```
CONVERT(expression, 'TypeName')
```

In your case this becomes (after updating the column type):

```
// specify integer column, not string
// then convert values to int and perform calculation
var calculatedColumn = new DataColumn
{
   DataType = typeof(int), 
   ColumnName = Column_Name, 
   Expression = "CONVERT(Col1, 'System.Int32') * CONVERT(Col2, 'System.Int32')"
};
```

If for some reason you *really* want your computed column to be a `string`, you *might* be able to use the following (untested):

```
// convert to int, perform calculation, convert back to string
var calculatedColumn = new DataColumn
{
   DataType = typeof(string), 
   ColumnName = Column_Name, 
   Expression = "CONVERT(CONVERT(Col1, 'System.Int32') * CONVERT(Col2, 'System.Int32'), 'System.String')"
};
```

I used integers because your examples are all integers. However you can pretty much use any type that is `IConvertible`. You just need to specify the proper *system type name* and **not** the C# *type alias* (ie. `int`) . For example if your values were `double`s you would use the following instead:

```
// convert values to double and perform calculation
var calculatedColumn = new DataColumn
{
   DataType = typeof(double), 
   ColumnName = Column_Name, 
   Expression = "CONVERT(Col1, 'System.Double') * CONVERT(Col2, 'System.Double')"
};
```

Note the expression syntax is used for both expression filters and computed columns.

Comment: Thanks this really is a nice summary and pretty clear to me, I seen other similars questions but none is this much complete.